# Can't Enable Integrated Webcam in Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, webcam

I used to work on my Virtual Box normally until it started giving me critical errors, so i backed up my machine and reinstalled virtualbox and loaded my backed up machine. Now i am working on a project that needs the use of the Webcam, so i use my PC's built in webcam usually. I used to enable it from the VM settings. However, now it the webcam seetings doesn't show in the devices. The photos below show the problem i am facing.

The image below shows that the webcam option is checked in the devices.

[image: Virtual Box Setting]

However, when i enter to enable my camera from the devices, i don't find the webcam options! (image below)

[image: VM settings]

Is it recommended to reinstall my Virtual box again? If a solution couldn't be found?

Answer (score 1):

The VirtualBox Extension Pack is required to allow Webcam passthrough.

Available here -

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: You have to shutdown any running VMs and start them again for the webcam passthrough to work.